# How to create aspect in Grails 3.3.2 for domain class save method?

Tags: spring, grails, aspectj, aspect

I want to create an aspect in grails 3.3.2 that is executed every time that the `save()` method of an object of my domain class is called.

How can I do it?

/************/

Edit:
@pavger

I have tried the following code, despite calling any method of ProyectoService, my Aspect never runs

Service Domain Class

```
import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Proyecto)
interface ProyectoService {

    Proyecto get(Serializable id)

    List<Proyecto> list(Map args)

    Long count()

    void delete(Serializable id)

    Proyecto save(Proyecto proyecto)

}
```

Aspect!

```
@Aspect
class MeAspect {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        println "Inicializado"
    }

    @Pointcut("within(com.sample.ProyectoService.*())")
    void isDomainClass() {}


    @Around("isDomainClass()")
    Object aroundSaveConnector(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] args = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs()
        println "Aspecto before"
        Object object = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs())
        println "Aspecto after"
        return object
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code that you've tried so far, please. We can't do all the work for you. Show us at least an attempt at the answer.

Comment: @pavger I added more details! Sorry for my first comment!

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. Maybe your build does not use the AspectJ compiler at all or there is another configuration issue. Maybe your sample class `ProyectoService` is in the wrong package, not in  `com.sample`. Furthermore, `within()` pointcuts expect a type pattern, not a method pattern. So it cannot work like this anyway, even if the first two issues are resolved. I will be happy to answer if I can recognise your issue after you edit your question.

Comment: the aspectj library use is compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.3.12.RELEASE'

This is the code that I have, depending on the configuration of the Poincut running or not, the problem is that I want it to run when the save () of an object of my domain classes is done

Answer (score 0):

There is an option, that you create on the Domain class.
It is an option on GORM

Events and Auto Timestamping
GORM supports the registration of events as methods that get fired when certain events occurs such as deletes, inserts and updates. The following is a list of supported events:

beforeInsert - Executed before an object is initially persisted to the database. If you return false, the insert will be cancelled.

beforeUpdate - Executed before an object is updated. If you return false, the update will be cancelled.

beforeDelete - Executed before an object is deleted. If you return false, the delete will be cancelled.

beforeValidate - Executed before an object is validated

afterInsert - Executed after an object is persisted to the database

afterUpdate - Executed after an object has been updated

afterDelete - Executed after an object has been deleted

onLoad - Executed when an object is loaded from the database

http://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/

```
class Person {
   private static final Date NULL_DATE = new Date(0)

   String firstName
   String lastName
   Date signupDate = NULL_DATE

   def beforeInsert() {
      if (signupDate == NULL_DATE) {
         signupDate = new Date()
      }
   }
}



class Person {

   def securityService

   String firstName
   String lastName
   String lastUpdatedBy

   static constraints = {
      lastUpdatedBy nullable: true
   }

   def beforeUpdate() {
      lastUpdatedBy = securityService.currentAuthenticatedUsername()
   }
}
```

Comment: this is great, but the idea of using one aspect was to make it dynamic for all my domain classes,

How is it possible to do it dynamic for all my domain classes?

Comment: You can create an super domain class and them extends all the domains class from this super domain and then use this

Comment: The reason why this is not valid for me, is because I need to be able to access the data of the object before it is modified in the database and the already modified data.

I understand that the way to do this is thanks to the Aspects.

Would it be possible to do it in another way?

Comment: You can do anything in the method.

Comment: You can access the data, and call anything else from there.

Comment: It works as a normal method. Sorry for the number of comments it was not jumping lines here.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, this problem could not be solved in an optimized way.